# How does a Titan form or regenerate when injured?

Tags: attack-on-titan

[image: muscles & bone on titan]
[image: golden lines on titan shifter]

Where does the muscle and bone to form a titan come from; or is it generated by the titan shifters themselves? If so how? And what are the golden lines when shifters like Armin transform?

Comment: Whoa no need to go spoiling that one titan shifter, lot's of people aren't up on the manga.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(spoilers)

If i remembered correctly, in the manga a character named Kruger explains some of it, he says that for what marley scientists can deduce all titans are linked throughout "paths" that have no limitations of distance or time, it carries memories and thoughts between the titans.

Now a theory is that the flesh and bones of the titans also travels throughout these paths, the actual source is unknown, but the scientists also speculate of something called origin of all organic matter, but it's not confirmed, every nation has his own true, we can only wait